# Precharging my capacitor manually - looking for feedback

Tags: capacitor, spark, capacitor-charging, sparkfun

This is my plan, to pre-charge my capacitor of my electric vehicle manually, to prevent sparks occuring when connecting my heavy duty battery. The cables can easily handle 600A as well.
Im asking here this so detailed again, as some people once have told me, that you can't do it like that.

Please let know a simple yes or no answer, if this is will burn my house down or not (yes= will burn my house down; no= will not burn my house down)

[image: manually pre-charging capacitor with simple resistor]

Comment: Same as this question asked earlier: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/607269/can-i-pre-charge-a-capacitor-to-prevent-a-spark-when-connecting-to-battery

Comment: @ocrdu only partly.

Comment: Design your system so that it happens automatically. Add a contactor, mechanically sequenced contacts or battery isolation switch with contacts that will do a precharge before connecting the battery. 600A is not something to screw around with.

Comment: @Kartman I have done that already but the automation is making more problems as my Mosfet got damaged and I don't have time to buy a new one. I just need to connect this once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this would burn your house down if it was an underrated resistor and or you left it in for long enough to burn and you put it above a vat of petrol or other flammable liquid, inside your house. Or you had some other error not obvious from the question.

But otherwise no, I do exactly this on my ebike at a smaller scale (84V, 2.5mF capacitors) all the time. The resistors don't last long for me because I'm just using 4x quarter watt ones... you might want to get a fairly hefty one, that's quite a lot of energy it'll dissipate to fill those caps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this made me laugh and helped a lot at the same time. Good to know, that you do the same thing with your ebike. THANKS! :)